# Prevent similar consecutive colours for a pie chart

Tags: elementary-number-theory, coloring

## Background

Calculating colours for pie chart wedges. Consider:

$$
\begin{align}
d(n)&=\frac{\theta}{t}\times n\\
\end{align}
$$

Where:

- $\theta$ is the degrees in a circle (360)
- $t$ is the total number of wedges (can be odd), and $0 \leq t \leq \theta$
- $n$ is the wedge number, and a whole number
- $d(n)$ is the calculated hue assigned to a wedge

For $t=12$ and $n=\{1,2,3,...,t\}$, the calculation in [LCH colour space](http://www.colourphil.co.uk/lab_lch_colour_space.shtml) produces:

[image: Pie Chart]

## Problem

Similar colours are adjacent, which is undesirable.

## Colour Swap

Algorithmically, wedges can be swapped. When the wedge number, $n$, is even:

$$
\text{if}\, n \leq \frac{t}{2} \text{, then}\, n=n+\frac{t}{2} \text{; otherwise,}\, n=n-\frac{t}{2}
$$

This would work, but I'm wondering if there's a better way.

## Question

What single calculation (using simple arithmetic, if possible) for $d(n)$ would prevent similar adjacent colours?

Comment: I suppose that "maximally dissimilar" means complementary...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given $t$ colours and $n$ in $\{1,2,...,t\}$, then:

$$
\begin{align}
t_e&=t+\left(1-\left(t\,\%\,2\right)\right)\\
n_a&=\left[(n-\left(t\,\%\,2\right))\left\lfloor\frac{t}{2}\right\rfloor\,\%\,t_e\right]+\left(t\,\%\,2\right)\\
d(n_a)&=\frac{\theta}{t}\times n_a\\
\end{align}
$$

The floor ($\lfloor\,\rfloor$) and modulus ($\%$) functions are implemented most programming languages:

```
te = t + (1- (t mod 2))
((n-(t mod 2)) * floor(t / 2) mod te) + (t mod 2)
```

Comment: Well- thank you for the reputation donation, even if you kind of answered your own question :D

Answer (score 1):

If $t$ is odd, then the obvious algorithm is to step around $t$ evenly spaced points on the colour chart by $\left\lfloor \frac {t-1}{2}\right\rfloor$ points each time, drawing the spikiest possible $t$-gram (the pentagram (13524), heptagram (147362), etc).

In general you can take the integer next below $\frac{t}{2}$ that is coprime to $t$, for a reasonably good solution. It isn't optimal for the special cases $t=4$, $t=6$ for which that integer is 1, when sequences $(1324)$ and $(142536)$ give fewer adjacent colour pairs. So I suppose there are larger $t$ where you can also do better, though I don't immediately see the pattern.

Comment: Possibly the optimal solution is, as Marco suggests, to split the circle into complementary pairs and then if $t/2$ is odd, to order the pairs around the $\lfloor t/2 \rfloor$-gram, setting each pair down in turn; or if $t/2$ is even, iterate.